# How to create cloudformation stack from existing resources programmatically in .net?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I want to create a cloud formation stack from existing resources programmatically in .net. I want to launch my application in that stack in purely automate process.
Please help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS offers a tool called `CloudFormer` that can be used to create a `CloudFormation` template from an existing stack. This tool runs on a `t1.micro` instance, can be started via a `CloudFormation` template and provides an endpoint that you can use to interact with it (if you load that endpoint in the browser you get a nice UI, but you could also interact with that endpoint from your own code if you mimic their UI).

You can read more about `CloudFormer` on:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

and

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/6460180344805680

If you're only looking to create the `CloudFormation` template once from your existing resources, then you won't really need to interact with the `CloudFormer` tool from your code as you can just use the UI to get your initial template. Once you have the CloudFormation template, you can re-create, update or destroy the stack programmatically trough the `CloudFormation .net API`:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_CloudFormation_AmazonCloudFormationClient.htm

Comment: I have gone thru the above resources but is there any way to form a cloud former template in .net.I want to upload and execute a file from my local computer to ec2 instance.

Comment: If you want to create the template from existing resources, you'll either need to interact with `CloudFormer` as I described or implement a similar functionality in your .net app. But you can always write your own `CloudFormation` template from scratch and use that, or simply generate your template once using `CloudFormer` and just modify it later from you .net code.